# Is the Froogaloop2 library / API still supported?

Tags: vimeo, froogaloop

In the last couple of days I started having problems with playing videos on our two websites (vimeo videos).

I use the Froogaloop2 API / library.

All of a sudden I cant seek and play videos. The videos just stall.

Has something happened to the Froogaloop2 library recently and is it still supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, they retired Froogaloop without letting us know. You need to migrate to their new player.js

https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#migrate-from-froogaloop

Hope this helps!