# how to play the vimeo video on query automatically?

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api

In the beginning,the video is show,but the it is stop.
I want to play the video when browser starts.

```
 <html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
        <!-- NOTE: ?api=1 and player_id at the end of the URL -->
            <iframe id="player" width="" height="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/62207569?api=1&player_id=player" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>

            <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

            <script>    
                var player = $f(document.getElementById('player'));
                player.addEvent('ready', function() { 
                player.api('play');
                });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: From what i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949778/is-the-froogaloop2-library-api-still-supported), this API seems not supported anymore. [This link](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#migrate-from-froogaloop) could help you

Comment: thanks.I will try to it.

Comment: I found the solved problem.here is code.

Comment: <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/267755712?app_id=122963&api=1&player_id=vvvvimeoVideo-1540380" frameborder="0" title="Winsystem Bruce Testimonial" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" id="fitvid0"></iframe>

Comment: <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

  function addAutoPlay(){
   jQuery("#fitvid0").attr("src",
        "https://player.vimeo.com/video/267755712?app_id=122963&api=1&player_id=vvvvimeoVideo-1540380&autoplay=1");jQuery("#fitvid0").attr("allow", "autoplay");
  }
  setTimeout(function(){addAutoPlay();},1000);
 });
 </script>

Comment: <style>
  iframe{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
  }
 </style> this is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The froogaloop2 js is not working now try to use **player.vimeo.com/api/player.js**.
Just try like this

```
<iframe id="player" width="" height="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/62207569?api=1&player_id=player" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
    var frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var jqueryPlayer = new Vimeo.Player(frame);
    jqueryPlayer.play();
    console.log('played the video!');
</script>
```

I have run this code, just check the out put 
[image]

You can refer to this https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#create-a-player for more details.

Comment: hello.Thanks for replying.I found the solve.this is following  .<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/267755712?app_id=122963&amp;api=1&amp;player_id=vvvvimeoVideo-1540380&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" title="Winsystem Bruce Testimonial" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" id="fitvid0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>

Comment: have to add  ' allow="autoplay'

Comment: Okay, but by this way also it will work. Any way your issue is solved that's great. :)